# Cypher Query isn't returning any Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some problems to receive some Nodes and relationships and I hope someone here can actually help to find my mistake!

Broken down:

I have three nodes:

1. a Node labelled :Person with the property firstname
2. a Node labelled :Event
3. a Node labelled :Question with the property id

Basically the Relationship are as following:

```
(p:Person)-[:CREATED_EVENT]->(e:Event)
and
(e:Event)-[:ANSWERED]->(q:Question)
```

I tried to query:

```
MATCH 
(p:Person)-[:CREATED_EVENT]->(e:Event)<-[:ANSWERED]-(q:question)
WHERE p.firstname = "foo" AND q.id=2
RETURN p, e, q;
```

But my query is not returning any Node at all.

I haven't created any Indexes yet. But if I read correctly you can only create Indexes on properties and it will only speed up your queries.

Can anybody spot a mistake?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is correct, then it looks like you've got the wrong direction specified on the ANSWERED relation:

```
MATCH 
(p:Person)-[:CREATED_EVENT]->(e:Event)-[:ANSWERED]->(q:question)
WHERE p.firstname = "foo" AND q.id=2
RETURN p, e, q;
```

If you still don't get results, would be good to create a sample graph demonstrating the problem at http://console.neo4j.org/?init=0

Comment: Thank you that was the correct Answer! Can you maybe enlighten my about that topic. I thought the directions would be bi-directional. (I thought I read that somewhere in the manual)

Comment: If you want to omit the direction when querying and treat it as a bi-directional relation then MATCH 
(p:Person)-[:CREATED_EVENT]->(e:Event)-[:ANSWERED]-(q:question)
WHERE p.firstname = "foo" AND q.id=2
RETURN p, e, q; will work too (leave off the direction). If you specify a direction however, only relations in that direction will be matched.

Comment: ah ok great thank you! I always thought you have to give a direction! You saved my day many thx!